# requestLayout() improperly called by CheckedTextView

Tags: android

I got this error in logcat

```
03-11 15:09:43.403    2317-2317/com.manning.aip.mymovies W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.CheckedTextView{238af57c V.ED.... ......ID 0,0-540,96 #1020014 android:id/text1} during layout: running second layout pass
```

My app load StringArray from resources and display it in ListView

This is my activity class that extends ListActivity

```
public class MyMovies extends ListActivity {

   private MovieAdapter adapter;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      ListView listView = getListView();

      Button backToTop =
               (Button) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_footer, listView, false);
      backToTop.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(getResources()
               .getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_upload), null, null,
               null);
      listView.addFooterView(backToTop, null, true);

      this.adapter = new MovieAdapter(this);
      listView.setAdapter(this.adapter);
      listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
      this.adapter.toggleMovie(position);
      this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }

   public void backToTop(View view) {
      getListView().setSelection(0);
   }
}
```

and this is adapter I'm using

```
public class MovieAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

//   private HashMap<Integer, Boolean> movieCollection =
//            new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
// more memory efficient way of doing things
   private SparseBooleanArray movieCollection =
        new SparseBooleanArray();

   public MovieAdapter(Context context) {
      super(context, R.layout.movie_item, android.R.id.text1, context
               .getResources().getStringArray(R.array.movies));
   }

   public void toggleMovie(int position) {
      if (!isInCollection(position)) {
         movieCollection.put(position, true);
      } else {
         movieCollection.put(position, false);
      }
   }

   public boolean isInCollection(int position) {
      return movieCollection.get(position) == Boolean.TRUE;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      View listItem = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

      CheckedTextView checkMark;
      ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) listItem.getTag();
      if (holder != null) {
         checkMark = holder.checkMark;
      } else {
         checkMark = (CheckedTextView) listItem.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
         holder = new ViewHolder(checkMark);
         listItem.setTag(holder);
      }

      checkMark.setChecked(isInCollection(position));

      return listItem;
   }

   private class ViewHolder {
      protected final CheckedTextView checkMark;

      public ViewHolder(CheckedTextView checkMark) {
         this.checkMark = checkMark;
      }
   }
}
```

Please help me solve this problem.